# Can't open Android Studio project: Nothing happens

Tags: android-studio

I'm running Mac OS X Catalina Beta

I recently forked a [GitHub project](https://github.com/omatrot/SimpleUsbTerminal)

After cloning the repo on my computer, Android studio does nothing when I select the directory to open the project. There is no error message.

What exactly defines a project for Android Studio? Something seems missing but I can't figure it out.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Yep, by restarting the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by restarting the iMac. Weird 8-|

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't marked yet as an Android Studio project. Try `File -> New -> Import Project...`, then hit the project you want to open and follow the prompts. Android Studio will setup the rest for you. (It's probably a little different on Mac.)

Comment: I get the same outcome. Nothing happens. Very weird :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Trust And Open project" window is visible and you Click on the "Trust Project" button. After that, `npx cap open android` should work just fine. Some other window had stolen the focus and I could not see it.